# Turing Machine Diagram

Tags: transition, diagram, turing-machines

I have a final coming up on Monday and was given this as an example of problem types for the exam. I was hoping someone could help me out with a diagram, with some pointers, or with anything relevant.

I have done other problems successfully, however, this particular one baffles me.

[image: Example]

This is NOT homework. I am not trying to get you to do work for me, but rather to help me learn and prepare for my final. Thanks in advance.

Here is a diagram I did, but it only works if x and y are of equal length...

[image]

Comment: If I understand correctly you have to write a Turing machine that validates a bit string as input. You have to check whether it conforms to the format `x`, then `y`, then `x` reversed then `y` reversed, where `x` and `y` can be arbitrary length strings of `0` and `1`.

Comment: You will find this much easier with a multitape TM

Comment: thanks Jacob. I am using multiple tapes. My biggest problem seems to be knowing when x stops and y starts (and then where y starts). In my example I used a counter, but it only works for equal length x and y

Comment: Does it have to be a deterministic Turing machine? Because it would be much easier to write this as a [*non*-deterministic Turing machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-deterministic_Turing_machine), if that's allowed. You wouldn't have to know when *x* stops and *y* starts (and so on); you'd simply have to "fork" whenever a given input character can be interpreted in two or three distinct ways.

Comment: I was just debating that with a friend in the class actually. The example problem does not clearly state whether or not determinism is required. I wouldnt mind learning how to do so non-deterministicly, I am just unsure on where to put the said fork.